# JSF EL and + or condition

Tags: java, jsf, el

What would be the best way to format the following condition as in EL?

```
#{bean.booleanValue and (bean.stringValue ne 'MYCLOSED' or bean.stringValue ne 'ALLCLOSED')}"
```

The brackets don't seem to be recognised as a valid expression but it is a requirement that the statement logically render as follows:

```
bean.booleanValue && (bean.stringValue != 'MYCLOSED' || bean.stringValue != 'ALLCLOSED')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the concrete problem. What exactly is the problem with the first expression? Did you get an EL syntax error? Or is the problem rather with the 2nd expression (which I can tell beforehand that this would indeed cause a XML syntax error in Facelets (note: XML syntax error, not an EL syntax error)). Please never omit the **exact** error/exception message from the question.

Comment: The problem is with the first statement. The second statement is simply to illustrate what I am trying to achieve if I was doing it on the back end. The first statement is used for an item in a selectOneMenu render. I don't get a error message but as it is, it causes all the items in the menu to disappear (In my experience this happens when there is a problem with an expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator for the first expression and if it evaluates to true then you evaluate the rest of the expression, else you return false.

e.g. `bean.booleanValue ? bean.stringValue ne 'MYCLOSED' or bean.stringValue ne 'ALLCLOSED' : false;`

This is what we currently use when dealing with multiple conditions in a single expression.